# Ubuntu Server 16.04 to Server Ubuntu 18.04 upgrade fail

Tags: server, upgrade

Restoring original system state

```
Aborting
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
=== Command detached from window (Tue Aug 27 11:24:22 2019) ===
=== Command terminated with exit status 1 (Tue Aug 27 11:24:32 2019) ===
```

My Server In Google Cloud

Comment: as par your suggestion i delete ppa. but same result. :-(

Answer (score 1):

> My Server In Google Cloud

You do not upgrade cloud instances. Cloud instances are as is and you lease them with the operating system they are installed with.  Any other method than the official one is taking a risk that is irrecoverable when there are problems: there is no recovery mode (live session or grub rescue) for cloud instances.

The method you should use:

You create a new instance with 18.04, you disconnect your personal data disk from your old 16.04 instance and attach it to the new instance. After you confirm the new instance works you can burn the old one. Same applies for backups: you create clones of your personal data disk and attach it to a new instance to create a 2nd, 3rd version.

Comment: Hi Rinzwind, I had upgraded 16.04 server to 18.04 server in AWS Cloud. But in Google Cloud i did't update. how is possible one cloud service in upgrade and second is fail.

Comment: Amazon is not Google. Basic rule: you do not upgrade cloud instances: -any- kind of problem during a boot means the end of the instance.